# Variable binding error in angular component

Tags: angular

Thanks.

I figured it out.

I am just learning Angular and am working with a tutorial that doesn't seem to have the error I am getting.

I am using Angular 12 and the tutorial is using Angular 10.

I have a component that has a variable in the selector in the .html file. I have the variable defined in the .ts file of the component. But I am getting an error that says the variable (dep) that is not known. If I take out the variable from the selector - it works fine. It is set up the same as the tutorial.

Not sure what I am missing.

The error I am getting when I save the file in Visual Studio Code is:
[image]

Here is the code code in the html where the selector is:

[image]

If I remove the highlighted code ([dep]="dep"), it compiles fine.

And the code in the .ts file is:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: share project with github, I will fix soon

Comment: Don't include screenshots of code: copy-paste it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

`app-add-edit-dep` needs to define `dep` as `@Input` like this

```
@Input() dep: any;
```

Comment: Tried that but it says: Cannot find the name "Input".

Comment: @tshad,  you need import `Input` with `import {Input} from '@angular/core';`

Comment: and, please check `app-add-edit-dep` is defined as component, and, if that is in other modules, that need be declare as `exports`